# Type III anova in R, aliased coefficients in the model

Tags: r, anova

I have one continuous variable that I want to explain by two categorical variables (FactorA & FactorB each factor have 5 levels).

| Dependent | FactorA | FactorB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 45.24 | "a1" | 3 |
| 5.34 | "a1" | 4 |
| 20.1 | "a2" | 1 |
| 36.2 | "a5" | 1 |
| 66.77 | "a5" | 5 |
| 12.90 | "a4" | 2 |

etc. 60 rows.

I am trying to do a Type 3 Anova with car package function Anova() like this:

```
model <- Anova(lm(Dependent~FactorA*FactorB, 
contrasts=list(FactorA="contr.sum", FactorB ="contr.sum"), 
data = myDataFrame), type="III")
```

It gives an error:

```
Error in Anova.III.lm(mod, error, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
there are aliased coefficients in the model
```

What is wrong with my data? I have been told that type 3 anova should be ok with different sizes of groups `(="unbalanced design")`. But is it a problem if some of the combinations have sample size of zero? I mean if there are no responses to e.g. factorA4*factorB3. I have no idea whether the problem is this or something else...

How can I fix this "aliased coefficients" problem? And please don't say remove something from the data because all of the rows are important.

Comment: welcome to SO, can you add output of `dput(myDataFrame)` ?

Comment: @Samet Sökel It says it is too long to put here

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You should check your `lm` model for multicollinearity. ["Aliased coefficients" mean perfect collinearity.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112442/what-are-aliased-coefficients)

Comment: @Roland To my knowledge, these factors should not be perfectly collinear. They are something like "amount of sunshine" and "amount of water supply" classified to groups. Not depicting the same thing as pounds and kilograms would be.

Comment: The collinearity probably only becomes apparent if you look at the variables produced by the dummy encoding. Study the design matrix. You can extract it from the `lm` object using the `model.matrix` function.

Comment: @Roland Thanks! I just don't know how to interpret this complicated model matrix.